# How to make backward node connection in a graph?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a graph with 4 nodes which are connected with other nodes. Each connection has weight. For example:

> A -> 5 -> B
>
> A -> 3 -> C
>
> B -> 4 -> C
>
> B -> 3 -> D

Each node has backward connection correspondingly. But I have a problem with realization of such backward connection. Here is algorithm (in words) of what I have now:

1. Create nodes (A, B, C, D)
2. Connect node A to node B
3. Set connection weight
4. Repeat 2,3 for other nodes.

Following this algorithm I have to make backward connections (node B to node A) separately. And if I have 100 nodes or more, it'll be a trial for my attention.

How to make these backward connections during connection creation?

Here is a Node class:

```
public class Node {
    private String name;
    private Map<Node, Integer> connections;

    public Node(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        connections = new HashMap<Node, Integer>();
    }

    public void connect(Node node, int weight) {
        connections.put(node, weight);
        //It is expected to make backward connection here
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a neural network (: You answer is dasblinkenlight's but I would suggest a design change like Azodious did.

Comment: @HericDenis, Yes, both variants are good. But dasblinkenlight's one is the closest to my needs. I need connection information during minimum spanning-tree search (Prim's algorithm).

Comment: Nice @Dragon, good luck! I didn't knew this algorithm, I'm not a Computer Scientist, I'm an Electrical Engineer that's why I thought that was a NN.

Comment: @HericDenis, anyway neural network is good example for this Node class reusage :) Maybe in future I'll use it for NN creation (:

Comment: Yes it is! The one I did use similar design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
public void connect(Node node, int weight) {
    connections.put(node, weight);
    node.connections.put(this, weight);
}
```

Since `Node` is used as the key in the `connections` map, don't forget to override its `equals` and `hashCode` methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
node.getConnections().put(this, weight);
```

But, i'll recommend a design change:

```
class Node
{
    String name;
    List<Node> connectedNodes;
}

class Branch
{
    Node a; 
    Node b;
    int weight;
}

// calling part of program
// initizaliztion of fields already done
public void connect(Node node1, Node node2, int weight) 
{
    // checks required:
    // if a branch already exists

    node1.connectedNodes.Add(node2);
    node2.connectedNodes.Add(node1);

    Branch branch = new Branch(node1, node2, weight);
}
```